# jQuery rotate and increase image at the same time

Tags: jquery, css

I have function to rotate image

```
$.fn.clockwiseRotate = function () {
$(this).each(function () {
    var self = $(this),
        degree = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        self.css({
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'
        });
        self.css({
            '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'
        });
        self.css({
            'transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'
        });
        degree++;
        if (degree === 360) {
            clearInterval(interval);
        }
    }, 1);
});
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eaQRx/2093/

but I would like not only rotate, but also scale image while it rotates from 0 to 1.
To set fo image css
`transform: scale(0);`
and change it to
`transform: scale(1);`

Is there any way to create two function and use them simultaneously, one for rotation and other for scale, or, I don't know, any other solutuin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/k_rma/L4g2C/)

```
$.fn.clockwiseRotate = function () {
    $(this).each(function () {
        var self = $(this);
        var degree = 0;
        var scale = 0;
        var interval = setInterval(function () {
            self.css({
                '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg) scale(' + scale + ')'
            });
            self.css({
                '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg) scale(' + scale + ')'
            });
            self.css({
                'transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg) scale(' + scale + ')'
            });
            degree++;
            scale+=(1/360);
            if (degree === 361) {
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
        }, 1);
    });
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for help, but I can't understand, why this script doesnt work properly for a few image ? http://jsfiddle.net/KGH2F/3/

Comment: Oh, now I see, sorry, my mistake. The script works fine, thanks a lot for help!